# How to improve the performance of this data pipeline for my tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a tensorflow model which I am training on [google-colab](http://colab.research.google.com). The actual model is more complex, but I condensed it into a [reproducible example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1H-eIdWVhN8FCeOTIirkNVwYMDIk0QNI6) (removed saving/restoring, learning rate decay, asserts, tensorboard events, gradient clipping and so on). The model works reasonably (converges to acceptable loss) and I am looking **for a way to speed up the training** (iterations per second).

Currently on colab's **GPU it takes 10 minutes to train for 1000 iteration**. With my current batch size of 512 it means that the model processes *~850 examples per second* (I would prefer to have a batch size of 512 unless other sizes provide reasonable speedup. By itself changing batch size does not change the speed).

---

So currently I have a data stored in tfrecord format: here is a [500Mb example file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fUZdXo8Kxhtmwr3pKusxvng5oEOY22NK), the total data-size is ~0.5Tb. This data passes through a reasonably heavy preprocessing step (I can't do preprocessing beforehand as it will increase the size of my tfrecords way above what I can afford). Preprocessing is done via [tf.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data) and the output tensors (`(batch_size, 8, 8, 24)` which is treated as NHWC, `(batch_size, 10)`) are passed into a model. The example colab does not contain a simplified model which serves just as an example.

---

I tried a few approaches to speedup the training:

- [manual device placement](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu) (data pre-processing on cpu, propagations on gpu), but all my attempts resulted in worse speed (from 10% to 50% increase).
- improve data preprocessing. I reviewed [tf.data video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIcqeP7MFH0) and [data tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets). I tried almost every technique from that tutorial got no improvement (decrease in speed from 0% to 15%). In particular I tried:

  - `dataset.prefetch(...)`
  - passing `num_parallel_calls` to map
  - combining map and batch in `tf.contrib.data.map_and_batch`
  - using `parallel_interleave`

The code related to data preprocessing is here (here is a [full reproducible example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1H-eIdWVhN8FCeOTIirkNVwYMDIk0QNI6#scrollTo=sOLX0JqKwqZt) with [example data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fUZdXo8Kxhtmwr3pKusxvng5oEOY22NK)):

```
_keys_to_map = {
    'd': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),  # data
    's': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),   # score
}


def _parser(record):][3]
    parsed = tf.parse_single_example(record, _keys_to_map)
    return parsed['d'], parsed['s']


def init_tfrecord_dataset():
  files_train = glob.glob(DIR_TFRECORDS + '*.tfrecord')
  random.shuffle(files_train)

  with tf.name_scope('tfr_iterator'):
    ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files_train)      # define data from randomly ordered files
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)             # select elements randomly from the buffer
    ds = ds.map(_parser)                           # map them based on tfrecord format
    ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True) # group elements in batch (remove batch of less than BATCH_SIZE)
    ds = ds.repeat()                               # iterate infinitely 

    return ds.make_initializable_iterator()        # initialize the iterator


def iterator_to_data(iterator):
  """Creates a part of the graph which reads the raw data from an iterator and transforms it to a 
  data ready to be passed to model.

  Args:
    iterator      - iterator. Created by `init_tfrecord_dataset`

  Returns:
    data_board      - (BATCH_SIZE, 8, 8, 24) you can think about as NWHC for images.
    data_flags      - (BATCH_SIZE, 10)
    combined_score  - (BATCH_SIZE,)
  """

  b = tf.constant((128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1), dtype=tf.uint8, name='unpacked_const')

  with tf.name_scope('tfr_parse'):
    with tf.name_scope('packed_data'):
      next_element = iterator.get_next()
      data_packed, score_int = next_element
      score = tf.cast(score_int, tf.float64, name='score_float')

    # https://stackoverflow.com/q/45454470/1090562
    with tf.name_scope('data_unpacked'):
      data_unpacked = tf.reshape(tf.mod(tf.to_int32(tf.decode_raw(data_packed, tf.uint8)[:,:,None] // b), 2), [BATCH_SIZE, 1552], name='data_unpack')

    with tf.name_scope('score'):
      with tf.name_scope('is_mate'):
        score_is_mate = tf.cast(tf.squeeze(tf.slice(data_unpacked, [0, 1546], [BATCH_SIZE, 1])), tf.float64, name='is_mate')
      with tf.name_scope('combined'):
        combined_score = (1 - score_is_mate) * VALUE_A * tf.tanh(score / VALUE_K) + score_is_mate * tf.sign(score) * (VALUE_A + (1 - VALUE_A) / (VALUE_B - 1) * tf.reduce_max(tf.stack([tf.zeros(BATCH_SIZE, dtype=tf.float64), VALUE_B - tf.abs(score)]), axis=0))


    with tf.name_scope('board'):
      with tf.name_scope('reshape_layers'):
        data_board = tf.reshape(tf.slice(data_unpacked, [0, 0], [BATCH_SIZE, 8 * 8 * 24]), [BATCH_SIZE, 8, 8, 24], name='board_reshape')

      with tf.name_scope('combine_layers'):  
        data_board = tf.cast(tf.stack([
          data_board[:,:,:, 0],
          data_board[:,:,:, 4],
          data_board[:,:,:, 8],
          data_board[:,:,:,12],
          data_board[:,:,:,16],
          data_board[:,:,:,20],
          - data_board[:,:,:, 1],
          - data_board[:,:,:, 5],
          - data_board[:,:,:, 9],
          - data_board[:,:,:,13],
          - data_board[:,:,:,17],
          - data_board[:,:,:,21],
          data_board[:,:,:, 2],
          data_board[:,:,:, 6],
          data_board[:,:,:,10],
          data_board[:,:,:,14],
          data_board[:,:,:,18],
          data_board[:,:,:,22],
          - data_board[:,:,:, 3],
          - data_board[:,:,:, 7],
          - data_board[:,:,:,11],
          - data_board[:,:,:,15],
          - data_board[:,:,:,19],
          - data_board[:,:,:,23],
        ], axis=3), tf.float64, name='board_compact')

    with tf.name_scope('flags'):
      data_flags = tf.cast(tf.slice(data_unpacked, [0, 1536], [BATCH_SIZE, 10]), tf.float64, name='flags')

  return data_board, data_flags, combined_score
```

---

I am looking for practical solutions (I have tried significant amount of theoretical ideas) which can improve the the speed of training (in terms of examples/second). I am **not** looking for a way to improve the accuracy of the model (or modify the model) as this is just a test model.

I have spent significant amount of time trying to optimize this (and gave up). So I would be happy to award a bounty of 200 for a working solution with a nice explanation.

Comment: Are you reading tfrecords from drive?

Comment: @mlRocks yes, I am reading it from gDrive. You can actually look at the full implementation in the full reproducible link from the question.

Comment: This may it be helpful :https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/overview#input_pipeline_optimization
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14857

Comment: @SalvadorDali it's the known problem. Because it's not a physical drive like attached to your computer, reading from it will be slow

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [suggestion from hampi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53434100/3574081) to profile your training job is a good one, and may be necessary to understand the actual bottlenecks in your pipeline. The other suggestions in the [Input Pipeline performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets) should be useful as well.

However, there is another possible "quick fix" that might be useful. In some cases, the amount of work in a `Dataset.map()` transformation can be very small, and dominated by the cost of invoking the function for each element. In those cases, we often try to **vectorize** the map function, and move it after the `Dataset.batch()` transformation, in order to invoke the function fewer times (1/512 as many times, in this case), and perform larger—and potentially easier-to-parallelize—operations on each batch. Fortunately, your pipeline can be vectorized as follows:

```
def _batch_parser(record_batch):
  # NOTE: Use `tf.parse_example()` to operate on batches of records.
  parsed = tf.parse_example(record_batch, _keys_to_map)
  return parsed['d'], parsed['s']

def init_tfrecord_dataset():
  files_train = glob.glob(DIR_TFRECORDS + '*.tfrecord')
  random.shuffle(files_train)

  with tf.name_scope('tfr_iterator'):
    ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files_train)      # define data from randomly ordered files
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)             # select elements randomly from the buffer
    # NOTE: Change begins here.
    ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True) # group elements in batch (remove batch of less than BATCH_SIZE)
    ds = ds.map(_batch_parser)                     # map batches based on tfrecord format
    # NOTE: Change ends here.
    ds = ds.repeat()                               # iterate infinitely 

    return ds.make_initializable_iterator()        # initialize the iterator
```

Currently, vectorization is a change that you have to make manually, but the `tf.data` team are working on [an optimization pass that provides automatic vectorization](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/bd962d8cdfcda01a23c7051fa05e3db86dd9c30f/tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/data/map_vectorization.cc).

Comment: Thank you very much. Based on my tests (on a bigger dataset) this gives me ~3-5% speed-up (not sure whether this is statistically significant or a random fluctuation). Not as much as I was hoping for, but very good for a 3 lines change.

Comment: @mrry I'm having non-scalar features in my TFRecords. While your solution worked fine for scalar features, I did not manage parse tensors via `io.parse_tensor`. I'm encountering the following warning: `WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting ParseTensor`. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 7):

I have a couple of suggestions:

1) After creating the batch, the entire batch is processed by the `iterator_to_data()` function. This isn't really distributing the task on multiple threads, atleast not at the api level. Instead, you could try something like this in the `init_tfrecord_dataset()` function:

```
ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files_train)      # define data from randomly ordered files
ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)             # select elements randomly from the buffer
ds = ds.map(_parser)  
ds = ds.map(map_func=iterator_to_data, num_parallel_calls=FLAGS.num_preprocessing_threads)
ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True) # group elements in batch (remove batch of less than BATCH_SIZE)
ds = ds.repeat()
```

you might also want to change a few lines in the iterator_to_data() fucntion as the input argument is not a iterator with the above changes.

2) You might also want to get the profiling information using something like `tf.train.ProfilerHook`. This can tell you if the bottleneck is with the cpu or gpu. For example, if the bottleneck is with the CPU, you could see GPU ops waiting for memcpyHtoD op to complete.