# Rewrite parser function to enable vectorization

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, vectorization

I am working with TensorFlow datasets. For loading image data from a record file, I have a function `parse_tfr_elem`, which currently only loads one example.

To speed up the data loading process, I looked into other questions, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53424152/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-this-data-pipeline-for-my-tensorflow-model/53585477#53585477). They suggest vectorization to process data batch wise. For my case, I have not found a possible conversion.

In my eyes, the critical point is setting the shape of the tensor. If not setting the shape, my network throws an error,

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: its rank is undefined, but the layer requires a defined rank.`

I am looking for suggestion on how to rewrite the following function to work on batches:

```py
def parse_tfr_elem(element):
  parse_dict = {
      'height': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
      'width':tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
      'label':tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
      'depth':tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
      'image_raw' : tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
  }
  example_message = tf.io.parse_single_example(element, parse_dict) #can be replaced by parse_example

  img_raw = example_message['image_raw']
  height = example_message['height']
  width = example_message['width']
  depth = example_message['depth']
  label = example_message['label']
  feature = tf.io.parse_tensor(img_raw, out_type=tf.uint8) #critical point 1
  feature = tf.reshape(feature, shape=[height,width,depth]) #critical point 2
  return (feature, label)
```

Two points I can't get to work are the parsing of the tensor `parse_tensor`and the reshaping (which would deal with different batch sizes, eg. the shape would be `[None, h, w, d]`

Thanks in advance for your help.

A code to play with is listed below:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import numpy as np

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

ds = tfds.load('mnist', shuffle_files=True, as_supervised=True)

ds['test'].cardinality()

ds_splits = ["train", "test"]

## Write features

def _bytes_feature(value):
    """Returns a bytes_list from a string / byte."""
    if isinstance(value, type(tf.constant(0))): # if value ist tensor
        value = value.numpy() # get value of tensor
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def _float_feature(value):
  """Returns a floast_list from a float / double."""
  return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]))

def _int64_feature(value):
  """Returns an int64_list from a bool / enum / int / uint."""
  return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

def serialize_array(array):
  array = tf.io.serialize_tensor(array)
  return array

for d in ds_splits:
  print("saving {}".format(d))
  subset = ds[d]

  filename = d+".tfrecords"
  writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter(filename)
  count = 0
  for image, label in subset:
    #rand_arr = np.random.random(size=(28,28,1)) use this as an alt for image to 
    #see how to load floats (set tf.float64 in parse_tensor below if so)
    data={
        'height': _int64_feature(28),
        'width': _int64_feature(28),
        'depth': _int64_feature(1),
        'label': _int64_feature(label),
        'image_raw':_bytes_feature(serialize_array(image))
        }

    out = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=data))
    writer.write(out.SerializeToString())
    count +=1
  writer.close()
  print(count)

## Load features

def parse_tfr_elem(element):
  parse_dict = {
      'height': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
      'width':tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
      'label':tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
      'depth':tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
      'image_raw' : tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
  }
  example_message = tf.io.parse_single_example(element, parse_dict)

  img_raw = example_message['image_raw']
  height = example_message['height']
  width = example_message['width']
  depth = example_message['depth']
  label = example_message['label']
  feature = tf.io.parse_tensor(img_raw, out_type=tf.uint8)
  feature = tf.reshape(feature, shape=[height,width,depth]) #needed or network throws error regarding missing shapes
  return (feature, label)



def get_dataset(filename, set_type):
    ignore_order = tf.data.Options()
    ignore_order.experimental_deterministic = False# disable native order, increase speed
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename)
    
    dataset = dataset.with_options(
        ignore_order
    )  

    dataset = dataset.map(
        parse_tfr_elem, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE
    )

    dataset = dataset.shuffle(2048, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.repeat() if set_type =='train' else dataset 
    return dataset

BATCH_SIZE = 32

tfr_dataset = get_dataset('train.tfrecords', "train")

for sample in tfr_dataset.take(1): #sanity check
  print(sample)

## Training and evaluation

def get_cnn():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size=3, filters=16, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=[28,28, 1]),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size=3, filters=32, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size=3, filters=64, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size=3, filters=128, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size=3, filters=256, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,'softmax')
  ])

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.01)
  model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
  return model

model = get_cnn()

model.summary()

model.fit(tfr_dataset, steps_per_epoch=60000//BATCH_SIZE, epochs=2)
```